# MongoDB best practice for recomputing computed data

Tags: node.js, mongodb

The [MongoDB docs discuss modelling computed data](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/model-computed-data/) saying:

> The application can either recompute the value with every write that changes the computed value’s source data, or as part of a periodic job.

Updating the data periodically is straight forward but not real-time enough for our use-case, so I wanted to know the best practice for hooking into every DB write in order to recompute some derived data?

Our application is written in NodeJS, using the native MongoDB driver.

I understand Mongoose offers a 'save' hook which sounds ideal for this, however it falls down pretty quickly as it doesn't apply to `.update`, `.updateMany` etc. (and `Mongoose.prototype.save` is pretty terrifying imo).

Does MongoDB support change events at the DB level which would be suitable, or perhaps the native driver (or another client?) exposes hooks designed for re-computing data?

Comment: Although the marketing spiel around MongoDB Change Streams don't really indicate they're intended to be used for computed data, I wonder if they'd be the best approach -- although I wonder how you would you ensure only one application instance is handling it.

Comment: The [Change Stream](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/change-events/) are not intended for recomputation per se but are  public API wrapper around oplog - one of the core internal mechanisms responsible for replication. Regarding race conditions - just ensure that your recalculations are idempotent so the worst thing that may happen if more than one instance handles the event is you waste some computational resources for identical updates.

Comment: The problem with mongoose hooks is that any other updates (manual from shell, other apps, etc) are not aware about mongoose and you may end up with inconsistent data.

Comment: Yes I think re-computing derived data would naturally be idempotent as it's expected to run many times over anyway, but the idea of having the number of app instances causing extra DB load isn't great imo. I was thinking we could make a single instance responsible for change streams or something like that.

re: mongoose hooks, we don't allow anything else other than a single service to access the mongo collections so it's not a huge concern but I take your point. I expect a periodic script would need to compliment both mongoose hooks or change streams in case they miss changes anyway?

Comment: I'm starting to lean towards just performing the update explicitly with any other updates which impact the computed data...def room for consistency bugs but more straight forward.